# NEXTJS Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, hyperlink

When I imported the Link from next/link, trying to pass the dynamic endpoint in my components. it gave me an error like this.

[image]

[image]

I look around that someone suggest to add a  tag, it also gave an error. Any one can help? thanks.

[image]

[image]

I followed the tutorial, he didn't get any errors. what's the problem?

Comment: Try it without the `<a>` tag as the error message says.

Comment: I would recommend you to paste your code  into your question instead of a printscreen.

Comment: if you use nextjs v 13 you must delete a tag

Answer (score 1):

It's not the first `<Link/>` in your component, it's the *second*  . The second one has no `href`. It only has `className="text-lg"`.